# How to get citation title from BibTeX? BibLaTeX/NatBib is not available

Tags: bibtex, citing

Is it possible to get the title of a given bib entry using strictly BibTex?
The setup requires the paper to strictly follow the template (BST) specified, stating that no additional 'basic' packages should be used (such as natbib, subfloat, etc).

Comment: Basically no: Entry data is not accessible to LaTeX unless the `.bst` file exposes some data in a way that makes it usable for LaTeX (and I know of no style that would do this for the title, except maybe `jurabib`). (This is what `natbib`-compatible styles do for author and year). There is the [`usebib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/usebib) package, but that is probably out of the question. ...

Comment: probably the answer is no, but the bst file could make it available, but as you have no given any information about that, it is hard to say.

Comment: ... It would be possible to do this by modifying the `.bst` file and adding a bunch of other code to the TeX file, but I doubt that would be 'better' than loading additional packages in terms of your template and you having to stick with it.

Comment: Of course you can always just type the title: `In his book \textit{The Origin of Species} \cite{darwin_oos}, Darwin goes on a boat trip`.